# Iterate through multidimensional PHP array and output values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a real headache trying to iterate through an array and output elements. Using the array structure below I want to be able to output each instance of partname.

The following loop outputs the first instance of partname. I can't seem to adapt it to loop through all instances within the array. I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

```
foreach($ItemsArray['assignments'] as $item) { 
    $partname = $item['grades'][0]['partname']; 
    }

Array
(
    [assignments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [assigntmentid] => 5101
                    [grades] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5101
                                    [name] => Advanced AutoCad
                                    [partid] => 6601
                                    [partname] => Draft
                                    [userid] => 82069
                                    [grade] => 53
                                    [courseid] => 6265
                                    [fullname] => Computer Aided Design
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [assigntmentid] => 5101
                    [grades] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5101
                                    [name] => Advanced AutoCad
                                    [partid] => 6602
                                    [partname] => Final
                                    [userid] => 82069
                                    [grade] => 35
                                    [courseid] => 6265
                                    [fullname] => Computer Aided Design
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: _“The following loop outputs the first instance of partname”_ – it doesn’t _output_ anything, it just stores the value into a variable. And if you don’t want that value to be overwritten in each loop iteration, then put it in an array instead at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just coding by slapping the keyboard. Write down what your function needs to do. In english (or whatever language you prefer). This would be something like:

> Foreach assignment, loop over all grades and store the partname of
>   that grade into an array.

And then code it:

```
function getPartnames($assignments) {
  $partNames = array();

  foreach ($assignments as $assignment) {
    foreach($assignment['grades'] as $grade) {
      $partNames[] = $grade['partname'];
    }
  }

  return $partNames;
}
```

So what did I do? I simply translated english to code.

Some few more tips: Use variables names that make sense. $item; $ItemArray; ... don't make sense. They tell me nothing

Comment: Ha ha ha! Sarcasm, common sense and coding advise rolled-up into one. What more could I ask for... well fried chicken. Genuine thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use an extra foreach in your loop:

```
foreach($ItemsArray['assignments'] as $item) { 
    foreach($item['grades'] as $grade) {
        echo $grade['partname'];
    }
}
```

Comment: we should enforce proper coding. using $variables like $item in an answer don't help